# trouble understanding lemma for normal basis theorem

Tags: linear-algebra, galois-theory

I'm having trouble understanding the following proof:

> **Lemma:** Let $K \subseteq L$ be a Galois extension and the Galois group $G(L/K) = \{ \sigma_1, ..., \sigma _n \}$. Elements $x_1, ..., x_n \in L$ form a $K$-basis of $L$ if and only if $\det [\sigma_i(x_j)] \neq 0.$
>
> *Proof:* The given elements are linearly dependent if and only if there are elements $a_1,...,a_n\in K$ not all equal to $0$ such that $a_1 x_1 + \dots + a_n x_n =0$. Letting all $\sigma _i$ act on this equality, we get \begin{align*} a_1 \sigma_1 (x_1) + \dots + a_n \sigma_1(x_n) &= 0 \\ 
> a_1 \sigma_2 (x_1) + \dots + a_n \sigma_2(x_n) &= 0 \\ \dots \\
> a_1 \sigma_n (x_1) + \dots + a_n \sigma_n(x_n) &= 0. \end{align*}
>   The above system of linear equations has a nonzero solution $a_1,...,a_n$ if and only if the determinant of the coefficient matrix (consisting of $\sigma_i(x_j) $) equals $0$.

I understand that if there is a nonzero solution $a_1,...,a_n \in K$, then this determinant must be zero.

Conversely, I do **not** understand why the determinant being zero implies there is a nonzero solution $a_1,...,a_n \in K$. Since the coefficients are in $L$, the only thing I should be able to deduce is that there is a nonzero solution $a_1,...,a_n \in L$, while in general $K \neq L$.

What am I missing?

Comment: Can we not use $a$ and $\alpha$ together...

Comment: I am sorry. I copied that from the book I found the proof in. (Which by the way is Brzezinski: Galois Theory Through Exercises.)
If you wish I'll replace $\alpha_i$ by $x_i$.

Comment: This is off-topic, but this reminds me of Bak and Newman's *Complex Analysis*, which also uses $a$ and $\alpha$ together in proofs. This is just horrible (although the book itself is good).

Answer (score 2):

My justification might be circular in your context since you are developing Galois theory, but if we forget this context and just view it from the outside (Galois theory can definitely be proved without your theorem), then I can justify it using [Galois descent](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/galoistheory/galoisdescent.pdf).

If the system of linear equations has a non-trivial $L$-solution, then the corresponding linear transformation has non-trivial $L$-kernel, which forms a vector space $V$. By Galois descent, $V^\Gamma = V \cap K^n$ is non-trivial, so the system of equations has a non-trivial $K$-solution.

Comment: This is not easy to follow, since I am not at all familiar with Galois descent. (Your source seems like a lot to digest.) Is it possible to translate this into a more elementary proof? If not, how come that the author of the book I found that proof in did not notice this big of a gap?

Comment: Indeed, Galois descent is not entirely elementary, as the statement involves tensor product (personally, I'm reasonably familiar with tensor product, so it's fine for me). I'll see what I can do.

Comment: Maybe the problem becomes easier if we instead ask this equivalent question: Must $(\sigma_i(x_1)_{1\leq i \leq n}, ..., (\sigma_i (x_n))_{1\leq i \leq n}$ form a $L$-Basis of $L^n$? If so, then the determinant can't be zero, so we would have proved the statements contrapositive.

Comment: How would you prove that it has no non-trivial $L$-solution?

Comment: $(\sigma_i(x_1))_{1\leq i \leq n} , ..., (\sigma_i(x_n))_{1\leq i \leq n}$ is a $L$-Basis of $L^n$ $\Leftrightarrow$ the determinant of the above matrix is not 0 $\Leftrightarrow$ there is no non-trivial $L$-solution. Maybe we can use Dedekind's lemma somehow?

Comment: Yes, it seems to me this follows immediately from Dedekind. @zinR

Comment: [Here](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/galoistheory/linearchar.pdf) (Lemma 3.4) it is proven with Dedekind. Is this what you had in mind? Actually quite a simple proof, and appearently from the same author whose text on _Galois descent_ was linked above.

Comment: @zinR - Yes, this is exactly what I had in mind. Sorry for answering so late. Since you didn't use the @ symbol, I wasn't notified.

Comment: @Pierre-YvesGaillard I see, thank you (also for explaining to me how to use the @ symbol).